# copy a range of Cells (A5 to C507) from sheet1 to sheet 2 after each 4th column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of Cells (A5 to C507) from sheet1 to sheet 2 after each 5th column ( i.e. on A5, E5, I5.... and soon) on click of button. But not able to change/increment the column on each click. Please advise.

Comment: Hard to help without your current code. Pleas post your current code in the original post using the edit flag

Comment: use a variable to store the column number on each click. make it public (outside of any specific module) so that it holds the value on each click. if you want it to keep count even after you close the workbook, then store the column reference last copied into a cell somewhere and then use that cell to find which column to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your task description, the Excel VBA code snippet follows:

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim maxColumns As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range, Rng2 As Range

    'set max columns pertinent to your task
    maxColumns = 100

    'loop through columns w step 4
    For I = 0 To maxColumns Step 4

        'set source range
        With Worksheets(1)
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(5, I + 1), .Cells(507, I + 3))
        End With

        'set target range
        With Worksheets(2)
            Set Rng2 = .Cells(5, I + 1)
        End With

        ' copy source range to the destination
        Rng.Copy Destination:=Rng2
    Next I
End Sub
```

You can modify the upper bound (Columns maxColumns = 100 in this example) per your task.

Hope this may help.